# When does High Rank start?

Tags: monster-hunter-generations

In previous monster hunter games (mainly the "ultimate" releases the west gets), there are three ranks: low, high, and G, and the game was very clear about when a rank started and ended.

Generations does not have a G rank and does not make it clear when high rank begins. It looks like village quests only go up to 6★, and the quests at that level are all about end-game monsters like Seregios and Shagaru Magala.

How can I tell when I'm fighting a high rank monster instead of a low rank one?

Comment: High Rank Monsters drop different items - eg. Rathalos Ruby instead of a Rathalos Plate, or scale+ instead of scale. Based on experience with past games, I'd not expect you to "naturally" move to High Rank -- look for some big climactic story-mode urgent quest first!

Comment: @RavenDreamer - that's exactly the thing, it doesn't look like there is one in this game. Or if there is, it's more subtle. Other games had separate low, high, and G "tabs" in the quest selection menu, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much like in non-Ultimate games like Monster Hunter Tri, the "offline" portion of the game, in this case the 4 villages, are entirely Low Rank, and only the Hunters Hub part of the game goes up to High Rank and Special Permit.

While you can eventually undergo High Rank quests in the villages (under 6*), they will only unlock once you make your way to High Rank in the Hunters Hub, and they will all be named "Advanced: [Quest name]".

Comment: So the key is to look for the HR requirement!

Comment: @Pyritie Indeed, but you won't suddenly find yourself in High Rank in offline mode is what I wanted to say.

Comment: @Pyritie It seems I was wrong, I corrected myself.